# Склонение "сидение" и "сиденье" по падежам

Tags: склонение, существительные

Странное правило.
Слова "сидение" и "сиденье" — одни и те же вроде, но в склонении отличаются.

Если нет мягкого знака:
*сижу на сидениИ, положил на сидениЕ.*
А с мягким знаком:
*сижу на сиденьЕ, положил на сиденьЕ.*

Почему? Лично мне ***сижу на сиденьЕ*** режет слух.

Answer (score 2):

1) **Итак, сижу на сиденье**. Режет слух? Уж скорее напрягает зрение, так как на конце слова произносится И, а пишется Е.

**Но правило о выборе окончания И, а не Е для существительных на ИЯ, ИЕ, ИЙ хорошо всем известно, как и парные варианты вида о Марии  — о Марье.** Эти правила долго-долго учат в школе, пока их не запомнят все, **это классика!** В Полном академическом справочнике правило звучит так:

Правило  [Розенталь. § 32. Окончания существительных](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=40#pp40)

**§ 71. Падежные формы существительных на -ий, -ие, -ия.**

Существительные с неодносложной основой муж. и сред, рода на -ий и -ие в предл. п. и жен. рода на -ия в дат. и предл. п. ед. ч. имеют в безударном положении, **в отступление от обще- го правила, окончание -и, а не -е,** напр.: гений — о гении, Василий — о Василии,  отделение — в отделении, армия — к армии, об армии; линия — по линии, на линии; Мария — к Марии, о Марии.

**При наличии вариантов на -ие и -ье, -ия и -ъя указанные падежные формы имеют разные окончания -и и -е**: ср., напр., вариантные пары типа **об умении — об уменье, в цветении — в цветенье,** **к Марии — к Марье.**

2) И вот учитель зачитывает этот текст, а ученики его заучивают.  Но почему-то никто из них не спрашивает: ** А почему?  Откуда  взялось это исключение из основного правила**?  И это очень интересный вопрос.

3) **Немного материала на эту тему**

[К. А. Литвиненко. Систематическій сводъ правилъ русскаго правописанія. | russportal.ru](http://www.russportal.ru/index.php?id=oldorth.litv18)

**§ 18. Ѣ, іи, ьѣ, ьи, е, и въ окончаніяхъ именъ существительныхъ.**
К. А. Литвиненко. Систематический свод правил русского правописания. М., 1915 г.

**Буква ѣ** въ именахъ существительныхъ ставится:

1) Въ предложномъ падежѣ единственнаго числа существительныхъ мужескаго рода, оканчивающихся на ъ, ь, й, и средняго рода, оканчивающихся на о, е: въ домѣ, на конѣ, въ сараѣ; объ окнѣ, при морѣ.

Но существительныя мужескаго рода **на ій и средняго на іе** имѣютъ въ предложномъ падежѣ **іи: объ Аѳанасіи, на Дмитріи; въ житіи, при имѣніи.**

Но какъ только въ этомъ падежѣ **і сокращается въ ь**, то ѣ обязательно возстановляется въ существительныхъ мужескаго рода: на Аѳанасьѣ, о Васильѣ.

Таким образом, правило можно определить как **традиционное историческое написание,** которое сохранилось в современном языке после реформы алфавита в 1918 году.

Comment: Спасибо, Ариночка, я это школьное правило хорошо знаю. Дело в том, что мой вопрос немного откорректировали: убрали концовку, в которой я спрашивала, не ожидается ли реформа языка, упомянула, что слово Кофе с некоторых пор стало и среднего рода тоже. По сути, мой вопрос о склонении -- это неудачная ловушка.

Comment: Вы задавайте по каждой теме отдельный вопрос, причем желательно, чтобы он был конкретный (не общего плана и не опрос мнения), а также чтобы он не повторялся (то есть не обсуждался на сайте раньше).

Comment: Да, я уже поняла, как это работает. Спасибо Вам большое, Арина.